# How to push XML file from server to android application via GCM server

Tags: android, xml, xml-parsing, push

I am trying GCM based android app to push messages from server to android client. I am able to push fix string with the following coe. I am wondering about the ways to push XML file from server and parse at the android application. I have done some research but I couldn't find push XML rather I found send XML file. Thank you

```
if (androidArray.size() == 1) {

    String registrationId = androidArray.get(0);
    Message message = new Message.Builder()
    .collapseKey(collapseKey)
    .timeToLive(30)
    .delayWhileIdle(true)
    .addData("message", Message)
    .build();

    Result result = sender.send(message, registrationId, 5);
```

Comment: Hey Guys! Your helps are really appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't push xml (or JSON preferably) to the android app. You send a simple message to the app.
when the app receives the message it then needs to go and pull the xml/json from the website with an http get request to the relevant url that will supply the xml.
The android app can then parse the response and do whatever you want it to.

Here is an EXCELLENT tutorial on C2DM (The forerunner to GCM) http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidCloudToDeviceMessaging/article.html
You should be able to work out the differences needed.

**UPDATE**

Google Android has a complete section on GCM which can be found here
http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html

Within that link there are getting started guides and a GCM Demo app

There are limits to the amount of data you can send and you should not rely on your data not ever exceeding the limits or Google arbitrarily changing the amount of data you are allowed to send.

Should either of those occur you would need to update your app so just do it right in the first place.

The message you send should act as a "key" to determine what action to take when the message is received.

**UPDATE**

If you are feeling REALLY adventurous you could use a custom sync adapter to help you consume your web services. It's pretty advanced stuff but if you are feeling curious about this then watch the Google I/O seminar on consuming RESTfull web services http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xHXn3Kg2IQE

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. So you are telling me that everything can be done from the android app right? I wonder what that push message contains? why not push XML file like string message?

Comment: "You don't push xml (or JSON preferably) to the android app." - Technically there's no reason why you can't push XML data to the app as long as the payload is no more than 4KB. It would be more efficient to do it that way as the app wouldn't then need to make an HTTP GET request for small amounts of data.

Comment: @TseringYangzom Go through that link to C2DM and all should become clear :) I'll update my answer with a bit more clarity though.

Comment: @Squonk, thank you. Well, my app is about integration of gmail calendars against the pre-installed android calendar. So what do you think is the best way

Comment: @jamesw, Thank you and i will. Actually, I did a while and looking forward to your clarity.

Comment: @jamesw : Agreed, Google *could* change the allowable size of the data payload but if they were intending to do that why would they increase the 1KB payload allowed for C2DM to 4KB for GCM? Suppose the payload was only 128 bytes (sufficient for a simple notification with URI, for example) what if they reduce it to 64 bytes? It could still break my app if my notifications regularly use 70 or 80 bytes, for example. How small an amount of data is small enough to prevent Google breaking things for app developers?

Comment: @Squonk It would be a pain, but they have done dafter things and the point is as developers we have absolutely no control. So eliminate the issue as best you can. What if they increased the limit to 100 MB and introduced charging for anything over a certain amount of payload on a monthly basis. That could end up costing you. They can and probably will change things again and we have no IDEA what impact that will have or what they will change. It's the age old problem of do I use libraries or write my own code? If you use a library do the best you can to minimize any impact changes might have

Comment: @jamesw : As you say, "the age old problem" and it's basically a moot point - we have no control or idea of what might happen. My original comment was meant to point out that GCM doesn't have to be used in a push -> pull model with the payload as "control" data for the pull operation. I don't use anywhere near 4KB for my data payload but I DO send complete data structures (at most 500-600 bytes but often less) which my app can process locally without any further network activity needed. How to use GCM best is really on a per-case basis IMO.

Comment: I am happy with you guys wonderful discussion against the future perspective of push-pull owned by Google. I hope there appears some better and easier solutions which could produce developers like us in ease.

Comment: Hey Guys, Can you please share me some coding in terms of pushing XML file using Google Cloud Messaging service. I researched but find quite tough to change every coding. Please

Comment: @TseringYangzom I have updated the answer with links to the Google documentation on GCM